# How to fix my code to write a variant of the solution of the SubSet Sum problem?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, subset-sum, array-algorithms

Consider the Subset Sum (SUSU) problem, I need to write a variant of the solution shown in class which will also print which weights are aggregated to reach a given sum. For example, if:

```
sum=12;
int[] weights={1,7,9,3};
```

the output would be: 0011 That is, for each value in weights, we write "1" if it was added or "0" otherwise.

With the help of a friend, I wrote the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr={9,1,7,3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SubsetSum(arr,12)));
}   

public static int[] SubsetSum(int[] arr, int sum){
    int[] output= new int[arr.length];
    return SubsetSum(arr,sum, 0, output);
}

public static int[] SubsetSum(int[] arr, int sum, int index, int[]weights){
    int[] output= new int[arr.length];
    if(sum==0)
        return weights;
    if(sum<0 | index>=arr.length)
        return output;
    weights[index]=0;
    int[] arr1= SubsetSum(arr,sum,index+1, weights);
    weights[index]=1;
    int[]arr2=SubsetSum(arr,sum-arr[index],index+1,weights);
    boolean isZero=true;
    for(int i=0; i<arr1.length & isZero; i=i+1)
        if(arr1[i]!=0)
            isZero=true;
    if(isZero)
        return arr2;
    else
        return arr1;
}
```

I expect the output of SubsetSum(arr,12) to be [1, 0, 0, 1] but the actual output is [0, 0, 0, 0].
I understand why it return this output from my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed method of returning result. Now used items are encoded in bits of `used` parameter.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/aTWBZb).

Main prints indexes of items (or nothing in case of fail) - `1,2,3` for may example, i.e. `1 + 7 + 13`

I'm not familiar with Java, so represent result for better viewing (perhaps something like `inttobinary`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr={9,1,7,13,3};
    int i = 0;
    int res = SubsetSum(arr, 21, 0, 0);
    while (res > 0) {
        if ((res & 1) > 0) 
            System.out.println(i);
        i++;
        res >>= 1;
    }       
}   

public static int SubsetSum(int[] arr, int sum, int index, int used){
    if(sum==0)
        return used;
    if(sum<0 | index>=arr.length)
        return 0;
       int a = SubsetSum(arr,sum,index+1, used);
       int b = SubsetSum(arr,sum-arr[index],index+1, used | (1 << index));
       if (a > 0)
          return a;
       else
          return b;
}  
}
```

P.S. Flaws in your code:
`isZero` is never changed.
If you correct logic to return non-zero array, it will be filled with all 1's - perhaps because `weights[index]=1;` changes the same array instance through common reference (don't know Java terminology). In my code at every recursion level there is own `used` instance, and modigying its bits does not influence on values in other branches.

Comment: Hi :) First of all thank you :)   
I'm sorry for my English but I try my best, can you please explain the algorithm?  What does the SubsetSum that you wrote return and what you did in the main? I'm a little confuse ><

Comment: The essence of algorithm remained the sama as yours - at every level of recursion function tries to include curren item or ignore it and checks whether solution is possible. The onlty difference - instead of result array I use `int` like "bit array". You should be familiar with bitwise operation `OR |` and `AND &`